# sql query to get last 7 day results between time ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I've query which gives the results with a column name called `alternative_time`.
It has the values like `2023-02-18 09:30:04` . I can do a query like `NOW() -INTERVAL 7 DAY)` and also time range like `03:00:00` and `10:00:00` but how do i combine both to get the results of last 7 days having the time range of between '03:00:00' and '10:00:00'. can i something like

```
T.alternative_time > NOW() -INTERVAL 7 DAY ('03:00:00' and '10:00:00')
```

- but this is not working.

Do we need to split the time and then store in a variable and then search with that string? can someone please help on this? Thanks!

```
select name 
from Profile_table 
and T.alternative_time > NOW() -INTERVAL 7 DAY ('03:00:00' and '10:00:00')
```

Tried with this but not working

Comment: You need a WHERE clause for the conditions.

Comment: can you be more specific please? like `where T.alternative_time > NOW() -INTERVAL 7 DAY ('03:00:00' and '10:00:00')` ?this also didn't work

Comment: Check date part and time part separately.

Comment: I'm not aware of that, hence asked here? do you have any info on that?

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of complex jiggling to get a string containing the right date and time and then convert that to a DATETIME you can do this

```
select `name`
from Profile_table 
WHERE `alternative_time` BETWEEN 
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY), ' 03:00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') 
        AND 
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE(NOW()), ' 10:00:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')
```

You could also just do

```
SELECT * FROM apitracker
WHERE `alternative_time` BETWEEN CONCAT(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY), ' 02:00:00') 
                AND CONCAT(DATE(NOW()), ' 10:00:00')
```

and forget about the conversion to a DATETIME data type

Comment: PLease show the full error message

Comment: Maybe you should use `T.alternative_time` all the bits I suggested dont use anything in your DB and work when I test locally, so the issue may be in the rest of your query.

Comment: [DEMO which works](https://dbfiddle.uk/GnMVfqdI) Maybe try and spot the difference between that and your actual code

Comment: Thanks! i tried changing some parts able to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

To filter results from the last 7 days with a specific time range, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT name
FROM Profile_table
WHERE alternative_time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND NOW()
    AND TIME(alternative_time) BETWEEN '03:00:00' AND '10:00:00';
```

Comment: This will only find rows where the time is between `03:00` and `10:00` it will miss all the rows that match the date but have a time of `10:00:01 to 23:59:00` for example. also the times between `00:00:00` and `02:59:59`

Comment: But that's what he wants, from what he wrote that's what I understood

Comment: Hmm, I didnt read it that way, but looking again, you may very well be right :)

Comment: What are the errors that you are getting?

Comment: I added your method to [my DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/NYpCOQIN) The OP can pick between the 2 now if they want